# Difference between dplyr::ntile and statar::xtile

Tags: r, dplyr, stata

My understanding was that `dplyr::ntile` and `statar::xtile` are trying to the same thing. But sometimes the output is different:

```
dplyr::ntile(1:10, 5)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5

statar::xtile(1:10, 5)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5
```

I am converting Stata code into R, so `statar::xtile` gives the same output as the original Stata code but I thought `dplyr::ntile` would be the equivalent in R.

The [Stata help](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?xtile) says that xtile is used to:

> Create variable containing quantile categories

And `statar::xtile` is obviously replicating this.

And `dplyr::ntile` is:

> a rough rank, which breaks the input vector into n buckets.

Do these mean the same thing?

If so, why do they give different answers?

And if not, then:

1. What is the difference?
2. When should you use one or the other?

Comment: You can check the source of each. `ntile`: `function (x, n) 
{
    floor((n * (row_number(x) - 1)/length(x)) + 1)
}`. [`xtile` is a little more involved.](https://github.com/matthieugomez/statar/blob/master/R/xtile.R) Base R might be something like `as.integer(cut(1:10, quantile(1:10, seq(0, 1, length.out = 5 + 1)), include.lowest = TRUE))`. The explanation of types in `?quantile` may also be helpful.

Comment: Documentation for Stata's `xtile` at http://www.stata.com/manuals14/dpctile.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm seeing the difference now. Though I can't see how to do it in base R. @alistaire your suggestion gives the same as `ntile`. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I've got it. It's just that `xtile` is using a different quantile algorithm type. Will write this up as an asnwer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @alistaire for pointing out that `dplyr::ntile` is only doing:

```
function (x, n) { floor((n * (row_number(x) - 1)/length(x)) + 1) }
```

So not the same as splitting into quantile categories, as `xtile` does.

Looking at the code for `statar::xtile` leads to `statar::pctile` and the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/statar/vignettes/vector.html) for `statar` says that:

> pctile computes quantile and weighted quantile of type 2 (similarly to Stata _pctile)

Therefore an equivalent to `statar::xtile` in base R is:

```
.bincode(1:10, quantile(1:10, seq(0, 1, length.out = 5 + 1), type = 2), 
         include.lowest = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 5 5
```